# LDAP custom attribute cannot be searched?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, attributes

I have some special custom attributes with my ldap setup. I have a custom attribute called "GroupCode". I have bunch of entries with this special attribute that I was able to write to the ldap database. Lets say that I have an entry with attribute "xyz" and another attribute with "wasd". I search with the filter "(GroupCode=xyz)" and "(GroupCode=wasd)" neither one of these search return anything. However, if I change the filter to "(GroupCode=*)", then it would return all the entries that have the GroupCode attribute. I have examined the attribute properties, and it looks normal, the apache directory studio shows it to be of "String" value, do I don't know why it isn't searching with the filter I provided. My knowledge with ldap structure is fairly limited as it is fairly complexed. Anyone have any idea, please let me know. Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What attribute type did you use? Did you enable "Index this attribute"?